# 'Array()' has private access in 'java.lang.reflect.Array' when trying to declare array in a class

Tags: java, arrays, class

I can't figure out what's wrong I am doing here .

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class arrays_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Array arr = new Array(5);
    }
}
```

I have already imported the required classes here. but when i am trying to create new array then it gives me an error that : `'Array()' has private access in 'java.lang.reflect.Array'` along with that in my instructor's IDE its working properly without importing anything.
[please take a look at my instructor's screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVoMd.png)

Comment: Are you trying to do reflection? Or is that first `import` statement of yours a misunderstanding on your part? The [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) is a utility class full of `static` methods — it is not meant to be instantiated. To quote the Javadoc: “The Array class provides static methods to dynamically create and access Java arrays.”

Comment: but IDE gives me only 2option over here that are : 
1. java.lang.reflect
2. java.sql

Comment: Was the instructor maybe making an `ArrayList`? This feels like some kind of misunderstanding between you and them

Comment: If you're trying to create an array, you're way off base.

Comment: also when i am trying according your suggestion it gives me the different error ::

`import java.util.Arrays;
public class arrays_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays arr = new Arrays(5);
    }
}`

Now the error is : 'Arrays()' has private access in 'java.util.Arrays'

Comment: If you are beginning student who accidentally wandered into that `java.lang.reflect.Array` class by mistake, **forget about that particular class**. Arrays are usually created like this: `String[] strings = new String[ 10 ] ;`. See the *Java Tutorials* [page on arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) by Oracle Corp.

Comment: @BasilBourque please take a look at my question again i have added a image.

Comment: Your instructor is likely using a custom library with methods to create like that and to use an `insert` method, however, this is not part of any standard library that I know of. If you have been provided a copy of that library then import it and use it like your professor (remove the reflect and SQL imports). If you have not been provided a copy of that library then you need to use normal java methods `type[] arr = new type[5];` just replace `type` with your actual data type, and to set a value `arr[x] = value;`

Comment: @sorifiend okay please tell me behind this code instructor using arrylist() or something else becasue it allocates the array element dynamically.  

.insert(1);
.insert(5);

Comment: I don't know what your professor has done, but it seems horribly misleading, or instruction has been misunderstood by students. If it was an ArrayList behind the code then you would not need a special class, because an ArrayList can be dynamically added to with `yourList.add(...)`. For a fixed size list, an array is what should be used.

Comment: remove the `import` statements and make sure there is an `Array.java` file in the same directory as your current `Main.java` (basically a class named `Array` that you should have done or that the instructor should've provided) - and tell your instructor it is very bad to use the same name as a standard class for own classes!  `Array` is a class in standard java that you are not supposed to use (as in given code); since your instructor is also declaring a class named `Array`, the IDE assumed that is to be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to do this is :

```
int intArray[]; 
or int[] intArray;
```

and in your code, you use public access modifier and it needs a class named `Arays.java`. The problem is that why you are stuck here because your instructor has made another class in the same package named Arrays but according to java docs, it is very bad to use the same name as a standard class for your own classes!

and then initialize your array like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] intArray = new int[5];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrays should be declared like this

```
int intArray[]; 
or int[] intArray;
```

For you it can be something like this:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] intArray = new int[20];
}
```

Comment: thanks but i know this way of array initialization but i wanna declare in the above way.

Comment: but why do you want to do it that way?

Comment: because java provides the way o doing this but why i am not able to do that i am just wandering about how i can declare

Comment: probable it is intended to use an own (self implemented or imported) `Array` class and NOT the reflection's one. (The imports were much probably automatically inserted by the IDE)